# Java Socket: client waiting server to be accepted

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, pool

I have a Thread pool which serves up to 3 thread. Each one creates and accepts a client. When the 4th client tries to connect, I want it to be informed that it has to wait until a thread/connection is free.

The problem is that, when 4th client starts the request with connect(), in theory it should get stuck for 500millis, than print the exception timeout string and finally try again until a server thread is free to serve it.
In reality, the client passes the connect() and of course get stuck in theObjectOutputStream without showing any error message...

Client side:

```
    boolean connected = false;
    Socket s=null;
    ObjectOutputStream dos = null;
    ObjectInputStream dis = null;
    while (!connected) {
        try {
            s = new Socket();
            InetSocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5056);
            s.connect(sa,500);
            connected = true;
            dos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dis = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while connecting. " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    //<CONNECTED: OPERATIONS TO DO>
```

Server side:

Server dispatcher:

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5056);

    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // only 10 connections in total
        Runnable task = new ClientHandler(ss);
        exec.execute(task);
    }
    exec.shutdown();
```

Server task:

```
class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
final ServerSocket ss;
private Socket s;
private ObjectInputStream dis;
private ObjectOutputStream dos;

// Constructor 
public ClientHandler(ServerSocket ss) {
    this.ss = ss;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    try {
        System.out.println("ClientHandler: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" <WAITING>");
        s = ss.accept();
        System.out.println("ClientHandler: "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" <CONNECTED>");
        dis = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        dos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //<OPERATIONS>
    }
}
```

Comment: I see a description of a sequence of events, and conclude the state reached does not satisfy you, but: What is your question? Please spell it out in back and white. (If the title gave a clue, that would increase your chances to get helpful reactions.)

Comment: @greybeard yes, I'm sorry. I hope now it's more clear